# Best Practices: Ensuring Backward compatibility with Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

When sending push notifications to our iOS or Android App we're currently sending localization identifiers within the notification's payload.

This results in bad user experience for users with older version of that app because they are presented a notification with the localization identifiers (which are not present in the older version of the app).

What are the Best Practices to deal with or prevent this situation?

Comment: One way I explored was to use background notifications and present local notifications with the localized text (or with a hint "the user should update the app"). But this approach is problematic under iOS since background pushes can be disabled or are not delivered if battery save mode is on or if the user force-quited the app,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Let you backend not only keep track of push token, but also app version. Your backend can then select the type of push notification per app installation.

You could keep track of the localization identifier of each app installation. Then you can send an already localized push notification.

Comment: I was hoping to save complexity on the backend but I guess this is the way to go. Also possible would be to track the language of the device and and send out pushes with localized text instead of relying on localization identifiers.